# will Java help me understand Processing?

Tags: processing, csound

It seems to me that most books are based on Java 6. I know next to nothing about Java.

I'm just trying to get Csoundo to work on Processing. Csoundo is a library for Processing so that you can use Csound technology inside of Processing and create your own graphic instruments.

I'm part of the Csound mailing list, username: Cacophony7

http://csound.1045644.n5.nabble.com/Trying-to-get-Csoundo-Processing-library-to-work-on-Windows-7-td5639076.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will help, but you might not not need to learn that much. You should take a look at how to build Processing libraries...

http://code.google.com/p/processing/wiki/LibraryGuidelines

There are templates and more...

http://code.google.com/p/processing/w/list